WSL (774) ERROR: UtilBindVsockAnyPort:286: socket failed 38
I'm  trying to execute a Python executable file within an Airflow DAG in a Docker environment and  I've encountered this error during execution :
<3>WSL (774) ERROR: UtilBindVsockAnyPort:286: socket failed 38
Can you provide guidance on resolving this issue
